# related_name argument not working as expected in Django model?

Tags: python, django

I recently got a ForeignKey clash in my Django model. I have the need to have two foreign keys (owner, assigned_to) ultimately pointing to the same model (a user).

From what I understand I need a `related_name` argument to solve that problem. So I did that:

```
assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(TaskUser, blank=True, null=True, related_name='user_assignment')
```

and

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(TaskUser, related_name="user_ownership"
```

But I'm still getting an error:

```
tasks.task: Accessor for field 'owner' clashes with related field 'TaskUser.user
_ownership'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'owner'.
tasks.task: Reverse query name for field 'owner' clashes with related field 'TaskUser.user_ownership'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'owner'.
```

Why am I still getting this error?

There is one catch, `owner` is in a super class (BaseWidget) and `assigned_to` is in a sub class (Task). Are there issues with using `related_name` in an inheritance relationship? Do I need to just override the inheritance of owner and redefine `related_name` in the sub class instead? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it possible that you have the same fields/fields with a similar related name in another model/app as well?

Comment: I have a BaseWidget (with owner) which is inherited by a number of models. So almost all of my models would inherit BaseWidget and hence owner. assigned_to is only present in Task

Comment: Is `BaseWidget` probably an `abstract` model?

Comment: Yes sir, it is an abstract model.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If you have `ForeignKey` relationships in an abstract base class every class inheriting from it will have this relationship. As a result of this you must not 'hardcode' its `related_name`, because all sub classes will try to create the same accessor on the realted class (`TaskUser` in this case).

You should better do something like:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(TaskUser, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_ownership")
```

See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) on this.

Comment: Great. Sheer genius. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much.

Comment: can you explain what this "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_ownership" expands to? What are those % signs I haven't seen them earlier?

Comment: @Mr.SuryaaJha from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name), `%(class)s` is replaced by the lowercased name of the child class that the field is used in, and `%(app_label)s` is replaced by the lowercased name of the app the child class is contained within.

Comment: Ohh I see @EyongKevinEnowanyo, one of the rare cases of Django magic

Answer (score 9):

If you are using related_name in abstract base class you need to use a '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s' in it. 
Its mentioned in django doc

[Be careful with related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)