# Django: related_name Reverse accessor

Tags: python, django

I have this model where InstitutePerson is a subclass of Person.

- Person

  - InstitutePerson
- Project

In Project:

```
participants_institite = models.ManyToManyField(InstitutePerson, blank = True, null = True)
participants_exterior = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank = True, null = True)
```

I get an error:

```
Project.participants_institute: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Project.participants_institute' clashes with reverse accesor for 'Project.participants_exterior'.
```

I thought that related_name would solve the problem but after seeing some posts ([related_name argument not working as expected in Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611410/related-name-argument-not-working-as-expected-in-django-model)) I'm not sure how to proceed because of the inheritance among the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `related_name` arg and define it manually
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

If you have two M2M field with same type Django can't generate properties on target modela automatically.

if you are not intereset in reversed direction, you can simply ise

`models.ManyToManyField(..., related_name='+r1')
models.ManyToManyField(..., related_name='+r2')`